# Lenovo T460p Synaptics Touchpad

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, synaptics

I recently changed to Ubuntu and try to configure my touchpad now. Such as multi-touch geasture to zoom in or I want to use the top-left corner of the touchpad to go back on websites (top-right corner to go forward).

On windows, this works like a charm since Lenovo provides a driver and a GUI to configure everything. I spend some time to figure out how to configure the same settings in Ubuntu 16.04.

All I found was hack yourself 50-synaptics.conf and good luck to find the right settings.

Isn't there an easier way to config the touchpad such as described above? The system settings are a bad joke. Speed and Scrolling? That's it...?

Hope anybody can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/gpointing-device-settings/

Check this if it contains what you need.

EDIT:

Or this:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/GnomeTouchpadManager

Comment: I'm definitely too dump for this...
GnomeTouchpadManager sounds great. But how can I install it? apt-get said, "gnome-touchpad-manager" cannot be found...

Comment: So I still don't get it. gpointing-device-settings is outdated and has no Ubuntu 16.04 support (and constantly crashing, if we believe several other posts in this forum).
GnomeTouchpadManager looks like its just a draft and there is no usuable program available yet. On launchpad.net it's just a blueprint...
So any other ideas?